# Injecting a class compiled on-the-fly with Guice

Tags: java, class, dynamic, dependency-injection, guice

I have a factory that reads a config file and generates a Class from source code while the program is running.

How do I pass a newly generated Class to Guice and have it create an instance from it. The class is not known at the time that the normal AbstractModule is passed to Guice.

Ideas? Solution?

EDIT: The problem is that the implementation for the Widget is compiled on the fly (always fresh if the file changes) and must itself be provided autmatically via Guice. The example AbstractModule looks like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
   protected void configure() {
     bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
     ... more bindings
   }

   @Provider
   public Widget provideWidget(){
        Class<Widget> clazz = ModuleCompiler.compile("src/WidgetImpl.java");
        // Clazz is a widget. But we do not know the exact constructors
        // We need to now produce a fully injected Instance as-if it was bound
        // like in a "bind(Widget.class).to(clazz)" statement
        // in the configure() method
        return (fully created injected class)
   }

 }
```

Complete answer:

okay ... Tavian did show a way. This works if the Injector is obtained (by injection) in the configuration module, it will be able to inject the newly created class like this:

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Config.class).toInstance(Config.getInstance());
        }

        @Provides
        public Widget provideWidget(Injector injector) throws Exception {
            Class<Widget> c = ModuleCompiler.compile("src/WidgetImpl.java");
            return injector.getInstance(c);
        }
    }

    MyModule module = new MyModule();
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);

    Widget w = injector.getInstance(Widget.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Injector.getInstance(Class<T>)](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getInstance%28java.lang.Class<T>%29), provided that the generated class has an injectable constructor.

Comment: LOL. Ooops. I down voted this by accident. But ... it does work. The injector can be injected into a provider in the AbstractModule and then used to instantiate of new class objects.